# Dynamically building CAML query in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2007

I have an requirement of get the items from the list depends on the ItemID.I have list which contains 5000 items in which I retrieve only 1000 items for that I will dynamically build the CAML query using JohnHoliday CAML.NET and the query have 1000 conditions at that time I got **Value does not fall within the Expected Range** error. The query works fine upto 150 items but it throws error when the ItemID increases.Could you provide a suitable workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

*If you are using [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx) then the [RowLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.rowlimit.aspx) property should do the trick*, but you should also check the item limit on the default view.

Source: [CAML return only 10 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318103/caml-return-only-10-results/2318161#2318161)

Comment: Thats not how I read the OP question - I think hes basically doing the equiv of a SQL IN - e.g. WHERE ID IN (1,2,5,19,37) - but its failing when using more than 150 conditions.

Comment: Ooooh, he has more than 150 conditions. The question has changed now to something different, there no more source code :))))). In such case I guess he is hitting a true limit...